# Connectivity and the minimum degree of bipartite graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

I want to find a condition on $\delta(G)$ (ex. $\delta(G) \geq an$) that guarantees $\kappa(G)=\delta(G)$ where $\kappa(G)$ is the vertex-connectivity of a bipartite graph $G$, and $\delta(G)$ is the minimum degree of $G$.

In other words, I want to prove that the statement

> If $\delta(G) \geq an$, then $\kappa(G)=\delta(G)$

holds for bipartite graphs.

I know that $\delta(G) \geq \frac{n+1}{4}$ implies $\kappa'(G)=\delta(G)$ where $\kappa'(G)$ is the edge-connectivity of $G$, and it is sharp.
Also, I proved that bipartite $G$ is connected if $\delta(G) \geq \frac{n+1}{4}$.
But I have no idea with the **vertex-connectivity**.
Here are my ideas to find such boundary $an$:

1. (Contrapositive) Prove the statement "If $\kappa(G)<\delta(G)$, then $\delta(G)<an$."
2. Use the statement $\delta(G) \geq \frac{n+1}{4}\Rightarrow \kappa'(G)=\delta(G)$. Find the boundary of $\delta(G)$ that implies $\kappa(G)=\kappa'(G)$, and then show this boundary also satisfies $\delta(G) \geq \frac{n+1}{4}$.

Would you help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This becomes true at $a = \frac{1}{3}$.

**Claim.** If $G$ is an $n$-vertex bipartite graph such that $\delta(G) \geq \frac{1}{3}n$, then $\delta(G)=\kappa(G)$.

*Proof.* Let $(A,B)$ be the bipartition of $G$.  Suppose $\kappa(G)<\delta(G)$ and let $X \subseteq V(G)$ be such that $G-X$ is disconnected and $|X|=\kappa(G)$.  Let $A=A_1 \sqcup A_2 \sqcup A_3$ and $B=B_1 \sqcup B_2 \sqcup B_3$ be such that $A_1=X \cap A$, $B_1=X \cap B$, and $G[A_2 \cup B_2]$ and $G[A_3 \cup B_3]$ are both a union of connected components of $G-X$.  Since $\kappa(G) < \delta(G)$, none of $A_2, A_3, B_2, B_3$ are empty.  Observe that the degree in $G$ of each vertex in $A_2, A_3, B_2, B_3$ are at most $|B_2|+|B_1|, |B_3|+|B_1|, |A_2|+|A_1|, |A_3|+|A_1|$, respectively.  By taking the average of these four numbers, it follows that for some $Y \in \{A_2, A_3,B_2,B_3\}$ every vertex in $Y$ has degree at most $(n+\kappa(G))/4$. Thus $\delta(G) \leq (n+\kappa(G))/4 < (n+\delta(G))/4$, which implies $\delta(G) < \frac{n}{3}$.

On the other hand, the following claim shows that $\frac{1}{3}$ is best possible.

**Claim.** For all $\ell \in \mathbb{N}$ exists a bipartite graph $G$ on $3\ell+1$ vertices such that $\delta(G)=\ell$, but $\kappa(G) < \delta(G)$.

*Proof.* Let $G_1$ and $G_2$ be copies of $K_{\ell, \ell}$ with bipartitions $(A_1,B_1)$ and $(A_2,B_2)$, respectively.  Let $X_1 \subseteq A_1$ and $X_2 \subseteq A_2$ both be of size $k$, and let $G$ be the graph obtained from $G_1$ and $G_2$ by identifying $X_1$ and $X_2$.  Note that $G$ is a bipartite graph with $4\ell-k$ vertices, minimum degree $\ell$, and vertex-connectivity $k$.  Setting $k=\ell-1$ proves the claim.

Comment: Can you explain more about 'identifying'?

Comment: I guess it means 'merging' each pair of vertices. Am I right?

Comment: Yes.  I have now also added a proof that it becomes true for $a > \frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: I have sketched the same proof couple of minutes ago, but it seems your one is much more logical! Thanks a lot for giving a brilliant idea.

Comment: @okw1124 You're welcome.  If you are satisfied with the answer, please click on the green checkmark to indicate that it has been answered.

Comment: Umm...in fact, I'm struggling with showing the average degree of $A_2 \cup A_3 \cup B_2 \cup B_3$ is at most $\frac{n+\kappa(G)}{4}$. Can you give me a clue?

Comment: Just add those four numbers up and divide by 4.  The sum is $2|A_1|+|A_2|+|A_3|+2|B_1|+|B_2|+|B_3|=n+\kappa(G)$.

Comment: I have observed that, but I thought the average degree is at most $\frac{a_2(b_2+b_1)+b_2(a_2+a_1)+a_3(b_3+b_1)+b_3(a_3+a_1)}{a_2+b_2+a_3+b_3}$. Can we show this one $\leq\frac{n+\kappa(G)}{4}$?

Comment: You don't need to average over those sets.  The proof shows that one of those four numbers is at most $\frac{n+\kappa(G)}{4}$. Therefore, for one of those four sets, the *maximum* degree of a vertex in that set is at most  $\frac{n+\kappa(G)}{4}$.

Comment: You mean, if we pick one vertex from each of $A_2,A_3,B_2$ and $B_3$, the minimum degree of those four vertices do not exceed $\frac{n+\kappa(G)}{4}$?

Comment: Yes, and it does not matter which vertex you pick from each of $A_2, A_3, B_2, B_3$.  For one of those four sets, *every* vertex in that set will have degree at most $\frac{n+\kappa(G)}{4}$.  I re-wrote the proof to make this clearer.

Comment: Thanks for brilliant idea!